# Falha ao usar inflection no Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, i18n

Estou usando `rails 6.1.4` e estou com problemas para a aplicação do pluralize em algumas palavras.

Preciso que o inflection funcione para linguagens diferentes `en` e `pt-BR`.

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural(/^(ox)$/i, '\1en')
  inflect.singular(/^(ox)en/i, '\1')
  inflect.irregular "person", "people"
  inflect.uncountable %w[fish sheep]
end

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:"pt-BR") do |inflect|
  inflect.plural(/$/, "s")
  inflect.plural(/^([a-zA-z]*)a$/i, '\1as')
  inflect.plural(/(s)$/i, '\1')
  inflect.plural(/^(paí)s$/i, '\1ses')
  inflect.plural(/(z|r)$/i, '\1es')
  inflect.plural(/al$/i,  "ais")
  inflect.plural(/el$/i,  "eis")
  inflect.plural(/ol$/i,  "ois")
  inflect.plural(/ul$/i,  "uis")
  inflect.plural(/([^aeiou])l$/i, '\1is')
  ...

  # Irregulares
  inflect.irregular "país", "países"
end
```

palavras como `baril`, `funil`, `categoria` (palavras terminadas em `l`, `ia` e algumas outras), etc. Não são aplicadas o plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a documentação da função `String#pluralize` o padrão do das regras de tradução tem sua prioridade sempre em inglês, usando o `:en`, por isso ao utilizar regras diferentes para cada idioma é preciso que passe o idioma que sera usado para as regras.

```rb
# pluralize(count = nil, locale = :en)
"Funil".pluralize(:"pt-BR")
```

## Links

[String#pluralize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-pluralize)